# android getActionBar() returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

Hello I am working on an android App. I am trying to create activity with tabs that swap. I am working with following tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

The problem is that in Main Activity it shows Null pointer exception at

```
 actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Does anyone knows why happens this?

My code:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
```

Comment: If you're using the action bar in support library, call getSupportActionBar()

Comment: @GeorgeD requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: Unrelated: addTab() method is deprecated, so you shouldnt use it anymore

Comment: @KushtrimP. what should I use?

Comment: There are ways to do it without third-party libraries, but the easiest way is using PagerSlidingTabStrip libray. Read:https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sliding-Tabs-with-PagerSlidingTabStrip .

As for the this question read: http://blog.perpetumdesign.com/2011/08/strange-case-of-dr-action-and-mr-bar.html

Comment: @KushtrimP. Si shtohen aktivitetet brenda ketyre sliding tabs. Nuk po gjej nje shpjegim

Comment: Perdor fragmente, jo aktivitete. Lexo linkun ne github qe e postova me larte,  e spjegon ne detaje se si perdoret.

Comment: @KushtrimP. sepse kam 2 aktivitete te cilat nuk mund ti kthej dot ne fragmente. si mund ti theras keto aktivitete nepermjet fragementeve qe krijova?

Comment: Hey guys talk in English here. Other user who will refer your question will find it not useful

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
actionBar = getActionBar();
```

Use

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Comment: cannot find symbol method getSupportActionBar()

Comment: Make sure u have extended your activity with ActionBarActivity